# How to resize Cypress screenshot using environment variables

Tags: cypress

In my Cypress test, I am trying to take a screenshot of the UI, & then re-size the screenshot.

My end goal is to be able to pass *height* & *width* values as environment variables when running the tests.

Below is my latest code, the code is based on this link https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/screenshot#Filename:

Spec file:

```
it('displays two todo items by default', () => {
    cy.screenshot({ x: 20, y: 20, width: 400, height: 300 })
})
```

And here is my `Index.js`:

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('after:screenshot', details => {
    console.log('--- Details ---')
    console.log(details);
  });
}
```

The above code does take a screenshot, but the image isn't being resized.

The image stays at the default dimensions *(1000 * 660)*.

Here are the deatils logged in `after:screenshot`:

```
--- Details ---
{
  testAttemptIndex: 0,
  size: 45768,
  takenAt: '2021-07-24T10:30:35.926Z',
  dimensions: { width: 1000, height: 660 },
  multipart: true,
  pixelRatio: 1,
  name: null,
  specName: '1-getting-started/todo.spec.js',
  path: 'C:\\Cypress\\cypress\\screenshots\\1-getting-started\\todo.spec.js\\example to-do app -- displays two todo items by default.png',
  scaled: false,
  blackout: [],
  duration: 861
}
```

Can someone please tell me how I can change the dimensions of the screenshot, & why this code isn't doing it?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want to *clip* the screenshot in which case the proper command is like this:

```
cy.screenshot({ clip: { x: 20, y: 20, width: 400, height: 300 }})
```

Screenshot will be clipped 20px from the top and left to the dimensions 400px x 300px

Reference: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/screenshot#Clip

Answer (score 0):

According to the cypress docs on [screenshot](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/screenshot#Arguments), you can use `cy.screenshot({capture: viewport})` - this way it will capture it in resolution according to cypress.json setup.